# jquery click not working with css 'position :fixed' property

Tags: jquery, html, css

When i am removing this property it is working fine, why is that so?

Here is the jquery function:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#flogo').click(function(){

   window.alert("clicked");

})
});
```

Here is Html code:

```
<div id="fblike" class="fixedlogo"><img src="images/likelogo.png" id="flogo" />    </div>
```

Here is css:

```
 .fixedlogo
{
position: fixed; //If i remove this line then jquery is working.
height:50px;
margin-top: -20px;
}
```

Comment: When you say that this feature "doesn't work", what exactly do you mean? There are a lot of different meanings for this. To help get your problem understood by other users, try adding some code or a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to help.

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/AcWmr/1/

Comment: I have posted a jquery click function which should show the alert, but it's not working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is likely an issue with `z-index` and not jQuery. jQuery wouldn't care what the position is set to. I suspect there is another element overlapping this one and blocking the click event.

Comment: I was about to write the same +1

Comment: In such cases it is hard to find which div / element is overlapping. Can we find the item which was got clicked?

Answer (score 1):

Make the position as relative for the div which have clickable items.

```
position: relative;
```